# How to fetch the data using Regular expression in OData Entity Framework through custom function

Tags: c#, regex, entity-framework, rest, asp.net-web-api

I need to fetch all value which is starting with a particular string suffix with "_" and only numbers.

Like

```
ABC_01, ABC_02,...
```

but not

```
ABC_01A or ABC_X01 or ABC_01_X or ABC_ABC_01.
```

I have used the custom function in OData Entity Framework like below.

```
public IQueryable<Values> ExistsName(string key)
{
    var names = from cc in db.Values.AsEnumerable()
                where Regex.IsMatch(cc.Name, "^" + key + "_(\\d)") || Regex.IsMatch(cc.Name, "(^|\\s)" + key + "(\\s|$)")
                select cc;
    return Names.AsQueryable();
}
```

How can we combine the both regular expression in one to fetch the data?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Above method will return the exact output. it's working code. but i want to clud both regular expression in one.

Answer (score 0):

> particular string suffix with "_" and only numbers

Use:

```
regex = '/^'+ suffix + '_\d+$/'
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/hD5uW7/1)

Comment: To get the exact string, i am using regex as below
`(^|\\s)" + key + "(\\s|$)`

after passing `ABC` , result is showing `ABC` and `ABC XY` as well

Comment: i changed the expression as `Regex.IsMatch(cc.Name, "^" + key + "$")`
now it's working.